# How the first controller(SiteController) is called in yii demo application?

Tags: model-view-controller, yii

I am new to mvc environment and it is the first time using/trying to work with YII framework.

After creating the webapp using **yiic** command , I get the whole structure build automatically.

My question is :

When I type localhost/myapplication/index.php in my browser I get the index.php page, but as much as I understood to display a **view** first a **controller** is called. I hope I am right.

I know that the SiteController is the main controller and in this controller all the actions are defined.

So, who calls the SiteController when i type localhost/myapplication/index.php for the first time, I searched for files but unfortunately I did not found any thing.

I hope I am asking a valid question and I am on right track.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about Yii Version 1 or Yii2  ? is not clear

Comment: version 1 I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii `CWebApplication` class has a [`defaultController`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#defaultController-detail) property. This property has been set to "site" by default. This makes `SiteController` as the default controller of your application. For changing it, you can add `'defaultController' => 'another'` inside your `config/main.php` file.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, this is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Typing   `localhost/myapplication/index.php`  you invoke   the `SiteController` in `myapplication/protected/controllers`. In this case you invoke the `actionIndex` and normally this action render the `index.php` contained inside the  `myapplication/protected/views/site/index.php` (You can change this default assignment inside the actionIndex in siteController)

Only if you use a `theme` setting properly the  `theme`  param in `/config/main.php`  the SiteController actionIndex render the `myapplication/theme/themeNAme/view/site/index.php`

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious answer and reply,but I am still not clear that how the SiteController is invoked who calls it, what if I write another controller ABC and I want this to be called on first load instead of SiteController. How the first call is made/invoked to SiteController.

I hope I am still on the track, If I am going out of track please let me know

Thank you

Comment: Site/index.php is  the default controller/action  invoked by yii when run. Every time you have an access to a yii app the myapplication/index.php is executed and run the yii component confinguration.  if you want change the default controller you must configure it see this link if si what you want  to do http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5372-change-default-controller-action/

Comment: Thank you very much Sir this is want I wanted.